# Autosetting search terms when implementing google maps in website (javascript)

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, geolocation, html

I'm using google maps to geolocate users on my website. After that I would need to find different services near them (I would like to have ability for webpage to input search term in google maps with geolocaion) Is this possible? and if it is how could I do it?

Comment: can you tell how search term? means location or pincode what?

Comment: @PareshGami I use geolocate api from maps to find persons location and after that I would like to use search option of google maps to find services near that spot (so javascrtipt would "search for coffe and on the map points would show nerby starbucks and other cofee shops)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following example for searching places.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=YOUR-API-KEY-GOES-HERE
```

You have to create project in google console using below link

https://console.developers.google.com

Then create `browser key` and that key is which you have to use in above url which mention.

Last thing you need to enable `Google Places API Web Service` from  `https://console.developers.google.com`

See below link for more detailed document.

```
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests
```

Let me know if any issue you faced.